# Is there a way to create an "Upload Only" permission?

Tags: sharepoint-permissions

Users will need to upload confidential documents that others in the same group should not be able to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can grant the item level permissions.

The User who uploaded the document can only see and edit that document.